# TypeError while inserting data into Django Model using DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to insert an object in a model called **User**. I am using **APIView** and **Serializers**.

I want to accept the **form-data** type request for this **APIView**.

**UsersApiView**

```
class UsersAPIView(APIView):

    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        request_body = request.data.copy()

        user_role_name = Role.objects.get(pk=request_body['role']).role_name

        request_body['password'] = "1234"

            deserialized_data = UserSerializer(data=request_body)

        if deserialized_data.is_valid():
            try:

                user_instance = deserialized_data.save()    

            except IntegrityError as error:

                return Response(error) # This is the part which return error.

            return Response({
                "success":"User has been created.",
                "status": status.HTTP_201_CREATED
                })

        return Response(deserialized_data.errors)
```

**UserSerializer**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    phone_number = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    password  = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    role = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        validated_data['role'] = Role.objects.get(pk=validated_data['role'])

        created_user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

        return created_user
```

Here is the model I have created and despite of using `__str__` I am getting `TypeError`

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique= True)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, unique= True)
    password = models.TextField(blank=False)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default= True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Businesses, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):

        return 'User Object ({})'.format(self.id)
```

This returns an error -

```
Internal Server Error: /users/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 103, in render
    allow_nan=not self.strict, separators=separators
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/json.py", line 25, in dumps
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 67, in default
    return super().default(obj)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type IntegrityError is not JSON serializable
```

I don't understand what possible could have gone wrong and how to fix it. 
This error is vague to me. I am not able to what could have possible caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a response with an object (an `IntegrityError`) that DRF does not know how to serialize too JSON. Depending on what you want to return, yo should go different ways, but make sure that what you return can de serialized. A possible approach could be returning a HTTP 400 Bad Request suing `ParseError` DRF exception:

```
try:
    user_instance = deserialized_data.save()    
except IntegrityError as error:
    raise ParseError(f"Cannot create the user: {error}")
```

The cause of the error, according to Django docs, is the following:

> Exception raised when the relational integrity of the database is
>   affected, e.g. a foreign key check fails, duplicate key, etc.

Comment: I want to return an `id` of the newly created object and it should be string representation of an object.